# ArcGIS MapServer publish custom Basemap

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-server

I have ArcGIS Server 10.8.1 and ArcMap 10.8.2. I have a basemap from Maxar in TIFF format. How do I publish it to the ArcGIS server?

Currently I can only publish those TIFF as a raster data layer onto the server (using group layer in ArcMap) and the selection of basemaps in the online map viewer doesn't allow me to add my own basemap either.

Comment: The optimal solution is to use a Mosaic Dataset, but that requires ArcGIS Image Server extension licensing.  You might be able to use a raster catalog instead of grouping a ton of images (which is the worst performing option).

Comment: In the online map viewer, I can click "modify map" and change that data layer to "move to basemap". Is there a way to work from there and save it as a basemap?

Comment: Also I can create a basemap setvice in arcgis online, as an alternative right? After that how do I link the online account to my arcgis server?

Comment: It basically boils down to following this guide: https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-online/mapping/custom-basemap-gallery/ I dont know if you are using Enterprise or AGOL as you frontend but to summarize you need a group with your desired basemap layers and the webmaps containing them and then set said group as your organizations/enterprise basemap group.

Comment: Sorry so just found out that my organization doesnt want to use arcgis online. Would an ArcGIS pro (instead of the non-pro arcmap) help?        And the problem I am having rn is not the lacking of basemap files (I already have them); the problem I have rn is to useit in / upload to my arcgis server. Basically I want a way of adding my existing basemap tiles as a basemap to the custom basemap gallery (make it accessible in arcgis server), without arcgis online and with arcgis pro.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the solution I posted to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/467584/upload-custom-basemap-to-basemap-gallery-in-arcgis-server-using-arcgis-pro-wit will do what you want.