# Upload custom basemap to basemap gallery in ArcGIS Server, using ArcGIS Pro, without ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-server, arcgis-online, basemap

I currently have all the raster cache tile files (provided by vendor) for the basemap.

I want to use those new custom basemaps in my web services in my ArcGIS Server (10.8.1).

Comment: ArcGIS Online is not of any use at all in publishing caches from Server, so referencing it just confuses the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The [Customize basemaps](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/portal/10.8/administer/windows/customize-basemaps.htm) process allows for the creation and use of custom basemaps. The steps are pretty straight-forward.

The process requires:

- Creating a User Group to access the Basemap Gallery
- Uploading your Raster Cache into a Service
- Incorporating that new Service as the new Basemap

After that, you should be able to see your raster within the Basemap Gallery.

Comment: The website doc you linked said to "Sign in to the portal website." as step 1. But our org doesn't want to use ArcGIS Online.

Comment: ArcGIS Enterprise includes "Portal" and "Server" (as well as web adapters, etc.) so with Enterprise you do not have to use AGOL.

Comment: That was really useful! Thank you very much Jason!